# Terminator won't start after installation with brew

Tags: terminal, homebrew, python

I am new to Mac, having moved from ubuntu. I would like to use Terminator terminal so I sucessfuly install it with brew: `brew install terminator`:

```
terminator -v
terminator 2.1.1
```

At first, I cannot run it with Spotlight search on Lounchpad only from Terminal. When I run it, I get the error message below:

```
ConfigBase::load: Unable to open /etc/xdg/terminator/config ([Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/xdg/terminator/config')
Unable to load Keybinder module. This means the hide_window shortcut will be unavailable
Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.
PluginRegistry::load_plugins: Importing plugin command_notify.py failed: Namespace Notify not available
ActivityWatch plugin unavailable as we cannot import Notify
PluginRegistry::load_plugins: Importing plugin activitywatch.py failed: module 'activitywatch' has no attribute 'AVAILABLE'
```

I copied the config file from ubuntu `~/.config/terminator/config` to my Mac and first log **ConfigBase** disappears.

How should I use Terminator on my Mac and how do I fix errors with module and plugin?

Comment: It works from terminal but does not work when launched via Spotlight? That's almost certainly missing the setup of PATH etc. Terminal runs .zshrc and .zprofile. Whatever is in there needs to be run in the terminator init process. Does terminator start a shell? It needs to be the same that terminal uses, probably zsh. This issue comment also has some overlap with your errors: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/98187#issuecomment-1084230607

Comment: Also, check out iTerm2, which is what people usually use on MacOS.

Comment: One more thing: right-click on the Terminator executable, choose *get info*, and, if it has that section, try setting "open with" to *terminal*. It's a bit indirect but might just work.

Comment: @MatthiasWinkelmann the PATH is configured and terminator is in first path `/opt/homebrew/bin`, I am able to see the binary from terminal but not over Spotlight. I tried reinstall command but after that I have missing terminator binary. Terminator is pawerfull for grouping consoles by name with template. Afaik iTerm2 cannot do that. File has already configured Open with to terminal.